# Add Object to Hashset with Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

```
 HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
 set.add("test1");
 Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();

 while(it.hasNext()){        
    it.next();        
    set.add("sf");    
    it.remove();        
 }
```

Throws me the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(Unknown Source)
```

If I delete the `set.add("sf");` it works obviously. 
But why can't I add something to my HashSet while using the iterator?

Comment: Because iterators are not designed to work in this way.

Comment: Please try to search similar questions before you add your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `Iterator` interface doesn't support adding elements to the `Collection` during iteration.

If you were using a `List` instead of `Set`, you could have used a `ListIterator` that does support adding elements during iteration.

This is specified in the Javadoc of `Iterator`'s `remove()` method:

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

The reason `add()` cannot be supported by `Iterator`s over an arbitrary `Collection` is that some collections, such as `HashSet` which you are using, don't have an ordering of their elements. An element added while iterating over a `HashSet` may be added before or after the current position of the `Iterator` (depending on its `hashCode`), so the iterator's behavior after adding the element will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator does not support add while iterating .In collection iterator use expectedModCount to check if it is modified by other.When you do some add using set reference modCount  value increases and expectedModCount not changed cause exception.

```
 if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

public interface Iterator {

```
boolean hasNext();

E next();

void remove();
```

}